# Angular 4 Firebase Observable with .map() apears two times on refresh and not reversed

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using Angular 4 with Firebase and AngularFire. I want to display on my Html code the first top 10 users, so my code is

```
 export class HomefillerComponent implements OnInit {
  topusers: Observable<any>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase,public authService: AuthService) {


        this.topusers = db.list('users', {
        query: {
         orderByChild: "totalscore",
         limitToLast: 10,
        }
        }).map((topusers) => {console.log(topusers);
        return topusers.reverse();})   
   }
```

My firebase database is:

```
"users" : {
    "Test1" : {
      "totalscore" : 50,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test2" : {
      "totalscore" : 30,
      "username" : "test2"
    },
    "Test3" : {
      "totalscore" : 20,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test4" : {
      "totalscore" : 10,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Zekes" : {
     "totalscore" : 14,
     "username" : "Zekes"
      }
  }
```

When I navigate in my angular 4 app everything works fine.However when I refrest the page I get two `console.log(a)` one with the reversed object and a second one with not the reversed object.So my html displays the not reversed object.
Do you have any idea of what is wrong?? It only happens when I refresh the page.
This is the `console.log(a)` I get when I refresh the page.[image: This is the <code>console.log(a)</code> I get when I refresh the page.]

Comment: I'm having the same problem... I need some help because I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I discovered what's happening:

The thing is that the `.reverse()` function not only returns a reversed array, but reverses the array itself. And this change to `topusers` result in the Observable firing `.map()` once again, which reverses the array back to its original form.

To solve this problem simply change the return statement to `return topusers.slice().reverse();`. The `.slice()` function returns a new copy of the array, which will prevent this problem.

Comment: This worked thanks so much.. sometimes the answer is so easy and so hard to find at the same time.. :)